# KableExtra math symbols

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

How can I insert 'equal or greater than' symbol in a kable? 
On the small rmarkdown doc below I tried two different ways based on some
internet suggestions but neither work. I did try the argument 'escape=FALSE' but
it does not work either. Thanks for any pointers...

---

````
title: "Math symbols in column headers"
date: "January 15, 2020"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

a <- structure(list(MLE = c(0.0839, 0.2082, 0.4194, 0.8237, 1.6201
), MME = c(0.0839, 0.2082, 0.4194, 0.8234, 1.6147)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L)) 

colnames(a) <- c("abundance of\n White Sharks\n $\\\\geq$ 40 inches","Percentage of \n White shark in 
the population\n $\\\\geq{40}$ inches")
```

```{r}
kable(a, "latex", booktabs = T)

```
````

This is what I get...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to end up with `\geq` in the Markdown file.  To get that, you enter `"\\geq"` in the R string, and specify `escape = FALSE` in the call to `kable()`.  That is,

````
---
title: "Math symbols in column headers"
date: "January 15, 2020"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

a <- structure(list(MLE = c(0.0839, 0.2082, 0.4194, 0.8237, 1.6201
), MME = c(0.0839, 0.2082, 0.4194, 0.8234, 1.6147)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L)) 

colnames(a) <- c("Abundance of\n White Sharks\n $\\geq 40$ inches","Percentage of \n White shark in 
the population\n $\\geq 40$ inches")
```

```{r}
kable(a, "latex", booktabs = T, escape = FALSE)

```
````

This gives me

[image]

To respect the linebreaks, you need to use the `linebreak` function from `kableExtra`, i.e. something like this:

```
colnames(a) <- linebreak(c("Abundance of\n White Sharks\n $\\geq 40$ inches",
                         "Percentage of \n White shark in the population\n $\\geq 40$ inches"))
kable(a, "latex", booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, align = "c")
```

which gives this output:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I use \n here since my column header is really long?

Comment: See the vignette "Best Practice for newline in LaTeX table" in the `kableExtra` package:  run `vignette("best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table")`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.