# Degree symbol in kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm trying to put the symbol of degree (º) in a table made it with `kableExtra`. The symbol which I obtained is a like in the image:

[image]

I need just the symbol (º) without the line below, like this:

[image]

I've tried with `$^\circ$` and with `\\degree`, with both my execution is halted.

Here are my options:

```
---
output: 
 pdf_document:
  number_sections: true
  latex_engine: xelatex
 template: NULL
 word_document: default
geometry: left=2cm,right= 2 cm,top=2 cm, bottom=2 cm
papersize: a4
header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{amsmath} 
 - \usepackage{booktabs}
 - \usepackage{pdflscape}
 - \usepackage[justification=justified,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false, font = small]{caption}
 - \usepackage{flafter}
 - \usepackage{float}
 - \usepackage{gensymb}
bibliography: library_tesis.bib
csl: apa7.csl
fontsize: 12 pt
indent: true
linestretch: 1.5
```

---

And here is the code for the table

```
atm <- read_csv("tablas/atmosfericos.csv") %>%
 select(-Cueva)

kbl(atm, "latex",
 caption = "Atmopheric conditions.\\label{tbl:atm}",
 col.names = c("Punto",
  "CO\\textsubscript{2} (ppm)",
  "T (ºC)",
  "RH"),
 align = c("l", "c", "c","c"),
 label = "atm",
 escape = FALSE, 
 booktabs = TRUE, 
 linesep ="") %>%
 row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
 kable_paper("hover", full_width = F) %>%
 pack_rows("Cueva de la Iglesia", 1, 6) %>%
 pack_rows("Sistema de Tubo de Lava de Chimalacatepec", 7,12) %>%
 kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59777426/10276092

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide the code for the table shown in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `\\textdegree{}`.

Example:

```
kbl(data, 
"latex",
 col.names = c("Primer",
  "Sequences 5'-3'",
  "Amplicon (pb)",
  "T\\textsubscript{M}(\\textdegree{}C)*",
  "Referencia"),
 align = c("l", "l", "c","c", "c"),
 label = "primers",
 escape= FALSE, 
 booktabs= TRUE, 
 linesep="")
```

Result:

[image]